# How can I read the depth value of a pixel when using multisampled FBO?

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer

I need to read the depth value of a pixel of a multisampled FBO. I tried using glBlitFramebuffer (drawing to a non-multisampled FBO and then calling glReadPixels), but glBlitFramebuffer gives me an error(invalid framebuffer operation).

Comment: You need to show some relevant code to answer this. Though chances are pretty good that one or both of your target framebuffers are incomplete.

Comment: You were right, a framebuffer was incomplete. Thanks.